# Compiler telling me I am not correctly using the this pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, this

Here is a picture of the error:
[image]

I have created a basic class that would hold the information of a sports team. When I am attempting to compare two teams with each other with the this pointer, I am receiving an error. Here are my two files. Hopefully, it is just a simple error.

**Team.cpp**

```
#include "Team.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

Team::Team()
{
  teamName = "The Strings";
  winNum = 0;
  lossNum = 0;
  numPlayers = 11;
  points = 0;
}

Team::Team(const char newName, int newPlayers)
{
  stringstream move;
  string strName;
  move << newName;
  move >> strName;
  teamName = strName;
  numPlayers = newPlayers;
}

void Team::display() // displays information about the team.
{
  cout << "Team name:" << teamName << endl;
  cout << "This team has " << numPlayers << " players" << endl;
  cout << "This team has " << winNum << " wins and " << lossNum << endl;
}
void Team::addWins() // increment the number of wins
{
  winNum = winNum + 1;
}
void Team::addLosses() // increment the number of losses.
{
  lossNum = lossNum + 1;
}

void Team::addPlayer(int nrPlayers)
{
  numPlayers = numPlayers + nrPlayers;
}

void Team::delPlayers(int nrPlayers)
{
  numPlayers = numPlayers - nrPlayers;
}

void Team::setTeam(char name[], int players, int wins, int losses)
{
  string strname(name);
  teamName = name;
  numPlayers = players;
  winNum = wins;
  lossNum = losses;
}

bool isBetter(const Team &other)
{
  if (this->points > other.points)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

int Team::getWins() // returns the number of wins for a team object
{
  return winNum;
}

int Team::getLosses() // returns the number of losses for a team object
{
  return lossNum;
}
int Team::getPoints() // returns the number of points a team has
{
  points = winNum - lossNum;
  return points;
}
```

**Team.h**

```
#ifndef TEAM_H
#define TEAM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// definition of class Dice
class Team
{
  private:
    int numPlayers,
        winNum,
        lossNum;
        int points;
    string teamName ;

  public:
    // default constructor: initializes the face of a new
    // Dice object to 1
    Team();
    Team(const char newName, int newPlayers);
    void display(); // displays information about the team.
    void addWins(); // increment the number of wins
    void addLosses(); // increment the number of losses.
    void addPlayer(int nrPlayers);
    void delPlayers(int nrPlayers);
    void setTeam(char name[], int players, int wins, int losses);
    bool isBetter(const Team &other);
    int getWins(); // returns the number of wins for a team object
    int getLosses(); // returns the number of losses for a team object
    int getPoints(); // returns the number of points a team has
};
#endif
```

Comment: Team::isBetter, you're missing the class prefix.

Comment: Thankyou so much, ive been staring at this for hours.

Comment: Please note that you should post actual error messages instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.